# Why does Postman show "Bad String" in this body of POST request

Tags: json, post, postman

As i was testing POST request on Postman with details shown in image. I am getting error when i Send this request.

> {
>       "FaultId": "Invalid post data, please correct the request",
>       "fault": "FAULT_INVALID_POST_REQUEST"
>   }

Am i missing something.
Details:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like the quote marks are not correct, maybe from copy and pasting from a specifically formatted document or syntax may be wrong.

Try removing/replacing manually or using this:

```
{
    "FirstName": "blah",
    "LastName": "blah",
    "UserName": "blah",
    "Password": "blah",
    "Email": "blah@blah.com"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the white spaces (tab spaces before properties) had a special encoding, to solve the problem, just delete them and replace them with spaces:

Answer (score 1):

Just click the `Beautify` button in `postman` or format the `JSON` in `VSCode` or use any `JSON formatter` in online.

[image]